# Why aren't zero energy states paired in supersymmetry?

Tags: supersymmetry, ground-state

In a general supersymmetric theory, given a supercharge $Q$ and Hamiltonian $H$, one generally has
$$[Q,H]=0$$
One can then say that given an energy eigenstate $|E\rangle$ with energy $E\ne 0$, then
$$H(Q|E\rangle)=QH|E\rangle=E(Q|E\rangle),$$
and so states with non-zero energy are paired in a supersymmetric theory. But it seems that this same argument should apply for the $E=0$ case. Why aren't zero energy states paired?

Comment: Hint: One should make sure that $Q|E\rangle\neq 0$ in order to have a pair.

Comment: I suspect that if $H|0\rangle=0$ then $Q|0\rangle=0$, but I do not know how to prove this

Comment: Oh wait, is it because $0=\langle 0|H|0\rangle\sim\langle 0| Q\overline{Q}+\overline{Q} Q|0\rangle=||Q|0\rangle||^2+||\overline{Q}|0\rangle||^2$ and so $Q|0\rangle=0$ and $\overline{Q}|0\rangle=0$ since this is a sum of positive semi-definite quantities?

Comment: Yes, that is the argument.